# Gitlab CI getting error with maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to pass CI test for my maven project and getting error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project TimeForStudy: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11.0.5 -> [Help 1]
```

It works successful only with 1.8 target version
maybe i should configure gitlab project settings and set maven dependencies repository witch contains required tagert java version for plugin?

```xml
<properties>
   <java.version>11.0.5</java.version>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>11.0.5</source>
      <target>11.0.5</target>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just use `11` instead of `11.0.5`...

Comment: @khmarbaise the same problem

Comment: Please make an example project and let us take a look...

Comment: @khmarbaise my maven pom.xml looks like:
[code](
<properties>
  <java.version>11.0.5</java.version>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.8.0</version>
 <configuration>
  <source>11.0.5</source>
  <target>11.0.5</target>
 </configuration>
</plugin> )[code]

Comment: As I mentioned before change `11.0.5` into `11` and a comment is not an example project.

Comment: @khmarbaise maybe you know how to configure JDK version at AutoDevOps configuration file. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426371/gitlab-autodevops-settings-for-jdk-version)

Comment: Unfortunately you are not helpful so I can't help here.